# Boost serialization invalid xml tag of derived classes with namespaced base

Tags: xml, boost, namespaces, boost-serialization

If I have a situation like the following, where a class B is derived from a class A in a different namespace, serialization oputput fails to validate tag name of base class producing "Invalid XML tag name".

How could I handle this situation?

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

namespace N {

struct A
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    int m_a;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_a);
    }
};

}



struct B : N::A
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(N::A);
    }
};



int main ()
{
    B b;
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive ar(std::cout);
    ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);
}
```

the output is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="9">
<b class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::xml_archive_exception'
  what():  Invalid XML tag name
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you use different namespaces, `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP` and `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP` do not work.
Instead, you need to use `boost::serialization::make_nvp` in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, I supposed that it was so. I was wondering if there is a standard solution. ":" is valid XML name character only in first position. I should redefine NVP macro to make an escape characters substitution.